# How to override Express API routes with React Router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, express

I have an application which is using React Routes and it's build is served with Express server where I have also routes for an API calls.

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const path = require('path');

const app = express()

// Serving Static Files and React
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build')));

app.get('*', function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
});

app.use('/api/files', require('./routes/files'))
app.use('/api/apartments', require('./routes/apartments'))
app.use('/api/keys', require('./routes/keys'))
app.use('/api/guests', require('./routes/guests'))
app.use('/api/transfers', require('./routes/transfers'))
app.use('/api/logs', require('./routes/logs'))
app.use('/api/auth', require('./routes/auth'))


const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000
app.listen(PORT, () => console.log(`Server started on port ${PORT}`))
```

It works fine, until the moment i go to http://localhost:5000/api/apartments - it's crash the app and just return blank JSON from API (but this is logical I guess)

I have setup in the Router to handle 404. If you go http://localhost:5000/api/ it will lead to 404 in React App.

**App.js**

```
<Switch>
              <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
              <Route exact path='/login' component={Login} />
              <Route exact path='/auth' component={Auth} />
              <Route exact path='/guest' component={Guest} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/guests/list' component={GuestList} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/apartments/' component={Apartments} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/apartments/:name' component={Apartment} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/keys' component={Keys} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/logs' component={Logs} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/manager' component={Manager} />
              <PrivateRoute exact path='/upload' component={UploadForm} />

              <Route component={ErrorPage} />
            </Switch>
```

Is it possible to make /api/apartments handle 404 as a React App or it's more right way to serve static build through separate server?

Comment: I would try something like this.  Add an error handler to your Express app.  Inside of that error handler, redirect to your React error handler url.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might not be the best solution but it might be OK for you

You can create a middleware and then check if it's an ajax/xhr request, it means that you can safely return api response as per url and if it is not and user hit some url like `/api/apartments`, since it is not ajax request, you can return `index.html` file and then react-router will handle the routes based on your logic. You can add redirect to `/` in routes at the end.

```js
function reactAppMiddleware(req, res, next) {
  if (req.xhr || req.headers.accept.indexOf('json') > -1) {
    // if it is an ajax/xhr request, you can even right your custom logic, maybe look for some header
     next();
  } else {
     // Return react app
     res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'client/build', 'index.html'));
  }
}

app.use(reactAppMiddleware)
```

Comment: Thanks, that solution works quite fine, for now, I didn't encounter any issues. May I ask your opinion if it's better to leave this kind of solution or split the front/back servers from the perspective of perfomance/security/etc. Thanks again!

Comment: I would suggest you to deploy your app on some static file hosting site like Aws S3 and you can use AWS Cloudfront (CDN) for to reduce latency. You can use firebase, netlify and many more. You can even use nginx 9https://nginx.org/en/ but that will cost more. Using file storage is the cheapest and best to deploy a single page app

Answer (score 0):

Create an error route and redirect from server.

```
<Switch>
    <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />

    <PrivateRoute exact path='/manager' component={Manager} />
    <PrivateRoute exact path='/upload' component={UploadForm} />

    <Route exact path='/404' component={ErrorPage} />
</Switch>
```

// App.js

```
//The 404 Route (ALWAYS Keep this as the last route)
app.get('*', function(req, res){
  res.redirect('/404');
});
```

Comment: Thanks for help, unfortunately, it solves the problem but crash the other part of application (react regular routes). The solution above works. Thanks again.